# How do I redirect a page to another page in such a way that they both look the same?

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect https://example.com/projects/issues/(some_text_here) to http://example.com/i/(same_text_here) in such a way that it /i/(same_text_here) shows the same page that /projects/issues/(some_text_here) shows. Is this possible? How would I do this. Please post the code I would use (along with helpful comments explaining why something goes where it does). Thanks!

**EDIT:** I believe I would have to use the htaccess file?

**EDIT 2:** By (some_text_here) I mean so random text, like a wildcard. It could be /projects/issues/34... or /projects/issues/hello. In this case first example should redirect to /i/34, and the second example should redirect to /i/hello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out in your `.htaccess`:

```
Redirect /projects/issues/ http://example.com/i/
```

Comment: by (some_text_here) I mean so random text, like a wildcard. It could be /projects/issues/34... or /projects/issues/hello. In this case first example should redirect to /i/34, and the second example should redirect to /i/hello

Comment: Would you tell me what happens?

Comment: Oh wait.... your last edit did work perfectly! I think I missed your edit by a second when I reloaded the page :P Thank you SO much! You are amazing sir!

Comment: Now I just need /projects/issues/(some_text_here) to send me to /i/(same_text_here)